# ¿Cómo se usa Git en RStudio?

Tags: r, git, rstudio

Hasta el momento, sólo he creado los repositorios desde GitHub.
¿Cómo se configura RStudio para poder crear repositorios y tenerlos actualizados?
De antemano, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a tomar el que creo es el caso de uso más simple posible, sobre esta base después podrías ir aprovechando más funcionalidades de Git y GitHub. Por "el caso más simple posible" me refiero a usar a Git como herramienta de control de versiones y a GitHub como servidor para sincronizar/compartir/respaldar tu repo y no para colaborar con otros users. Dicho de otro modo: trabajarías directamente sobre el `branch` principal (`master` o `main`), no integrarías cambios con `merge` ni aceptarías solicitudes de incorporación (pull requests). Es un uso muy rudimentario de Git, pero así y todo es sumamente útil. Si te interesa, por ejemplo, crear un blog con blogdown, esto va a ser suficiente para la parte Git del asunto.

Voy paso a paso:

1. Asegurate de tener instalado `Git` en tu computadora.

En la mayoría de las distribuciones de Linux viene ya instalado o es muy fácil de instalar. Para Windows es necesario descargarlo e instalarlo, aunque creo que Rstudio se encarga de hacerlo cuando es necesario (no verificado). Para macOS es necesario instalar las herramientas de desarrollador.

2. Decídete por un método de acceso y autenticación en GitHub/GitLab. La forma más simple al principio es hacer la conexión por `https` y autenticarse con usuario y contraseña cada vez que haces un `push` o `pull` a tu repositorio. A largo plazo es molesto poner la contraseña cada vez y quizás sea mejor idea crear una clave `ssh`. Hacerlo no es tan difícil, pero puede ser un poco intimidante al principio, así que omito esta opción.
3. Crea un repositorio en GitHub/GitLab y dale inicio creando un archivo `readme`. Te da esa opción directo en la interfaz, es muy fácil y te simplifica algunos pasos que vienen después. Ya que estás en tu repo ve al botón verde `Code` y ahí busca la opción `Clone` en la pestaña `HTTPS`. Copia la dirección, que debería ser algo así como `https://github.com/tu_usuario/tu_repo.git`
4. Crea un proyecto nuevo en Rstudio. En las opciones de `New Project` selecciona `Version Control`, luego `Git`. En el siguiente cuadro pega la url de tu repo e indica de qué directorio local (de tu compu) será subdirectorio el repo. Eso para no perderlo después ;)
5. Cuando des click a `Create Project` debería pedirte las credenciales de GitHub o hacerse automática si tienes bien configuradas las credenciales `ssh`. Listo!
6. Ya puedes empezar a poblar tu repo: armar el proyecto propiamente dicho. Puedes copiar archivos, crear unos nuevos, etc. Si estás migrando a Git un proyecto existente es más fácil copiar los archivos de ese proyecto a la carpeta del proyecto nuevo que subir el proyecto existente a Git desde la carpeta en la que estaba. Se puede hacer lo segundo, pero es más latoso.
7. Hacer cambios, `commits` y `push`. Para ponerlo de manera muy simple en `Git` tienes tres niveles de "guardado":

- puedes guardar un archivo. En ese caso no pasa nada en `Git`, solo registra que hay un cambio, pero el repo sigue igual.
- puedes hacer `commit` de los cambios de uno o más archivos. Cambios incluye crear o borrar un archivo, cambiarle el nombre, modificarlo, etc. En ese caso sí se modifica el repositorio local, pero no se modifica el repositorio remoto en GitHub. Para hacer un commit vas al ícono de Git en Rstudio o usas el atajo `Ctr-Alt-M`. Ahí hay un cuadro de opciones: lo obligatorio es seleccionar los archivos que quieres registrar en este commit y agregar un mensaje de commit mencionando que cambios estás haciendo.
- `push` Con uno o más commits hechos ya puedes "sincronizar" con el repositorio remoto en GitHub. En el menú de Git de Rstudio vas a `Push Branches`. Te va a pedir usuario y contraseña y si todo sale bien rápidamente el proceso estará listo.

Este es el uso súper básico. Te sirve para hacer control de cambios: el punto en el que quedó tu proyecto en cada `commit` queda registrado y puedes revertir tu proyecto a ese punto con relativa facilidad. Te sirve para tener un respaldo de tu proyecto: si pierdes o se corrompe el proyecto local puedes descargar tu proyecto desde GitHub y revertir a cualquier punto del mismo. Te sirve en principio para sincronizarlo entre varias computadoras que uses (deberías aprender a usar `pull` para eso, pero no están difícil).

Algunos tips adicionales:

- Hay un archivo que se llama `gitignore`. Es un archivo de texto plano en el que puedes poner patrones en regex de los archivos que se ignoran en los commits. Rstudio por defecto crea un gitignore bastante útil que omite archivos que no tiene caso sincronizar, pero quizás quieras agregar otros archivos a ignorar, por ejemplo, archivos .pdf con `*.pdf` o base de datos muy pesadas en formato binario.
- No es buena idea poner un repositorio de Git en la carpeta de DropBox o similares. Tanto DropBox como Git monitorean los archivos por cambios y hacen también pequeños cambios para ese tracking. En algún momento pueden "pelearse" por quien controla esos archivos. Esto puede ser problemático si estás usando Git para sincronizar un proyecto en dos computadoras. Mejor usar Git, te ofrece lo que DropBox, pero con más control y capacidades.

Espero que te sirva. Suerte.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda,